# I am making a game and I need it to add up each time they lose and or win in java guy

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

I have this and its in an action listener. If i lose it will display 1. It then resets the board and 1 will stay there which is what I want.. Then if i lose again it doesn't change the 1 to a 2. Same problems goes for wins. I hope this is enough information.

```
if (game.getGameStatus() == GameStatus.Lost) {
    displayBoard();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lose \nThe game will     reset");
    //exposeMines = false;
    game.reset();
    displayBoard();

    int losses = 0;
    losses = losses + 1;
    String lost = Integer.toString(losses);
    jtfLosses.setText(String.format(lost));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining "int losses = 0" everytime you enter your if-statement, it is getting overwritten by 0, then you add 1 again, which results in 1 everytime.

so defining

```
int losses = 0;
```

before

```
if (game.getGameStatus() == GameStatus.Lost) {
...
```

would fix the problem, like this:

```
int losses = 0; 
if (game.getGameStatus() == GameStatus.Lost) {
...
```

**but be careful, this solution is just to show you, what the problem is, to actually make it correct, you should use a member-variable, and not pollute the global name-space**

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite the number of losses with 0 every time, then increment that by one. Initialize the variable `losses` outside of this method and don't do it every time you want to increment it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use properties file to store this information like [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/)
you use

```
PlayerLoose = 2
PlayerWin = 3
```

than you can use

```
    int loose =(prop.getProperty("PlayerLoose"));
    loose++;
    prop.setProperty("PlayerLoose", loose+"");

    String lost = Integer.toString(loose);
    jtfLosses.setText(String.format(lost));
```